# What does VSP mean in the book The Original Scots Colonists of Early America, 1612-1783?

Tags: united-states, scotland, abbreviations, books

In the book ''The Original Scots Colonists of Early America, 1612-1783'' by David Dobson, published in Baltimore by the Genealogical Publishing Co. in 1984, I find on [page 349](https://www.ancestry.com/imageviewer/collections/48520/images/ScotsColonistsAm-000933-349) it lists an entry for James Wood that reads:

> 7086. Wood, James, Jacobite, tr. 29 June 1716, fr. Liverpool to Jamaica or Va, in *Elizabeth & Anne*, arr. York Va. (SPC.1716.310)(CTB.31.208)(VSP.1.185)

According to what I did find in the [list of abbreviations](https://www.ancestry.com/imageviewer/collections/48520/images/ScotsColonistsAm-000580-viii):

- `SPC`: Calendar of State Papers, America and the West Indies. London, 1880. *Series*
- `CTB`: Calendar of Treasury Books. London, 1904. *Series*

However, it does not include `VSP`.  What does this abbreviation mean in this book?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

The book '*The Original Scots Colonists of Early America, 1612-1783*'' by David Dobson is also available on [archive.org](https://archive.org/details/originalscotscol00dobs/page/n9/mode/2up).  Abbreviations are listed at the beginning of the book, but as you observed, VSP is not there.

However, all those I checked whose entry included a 'VSP' reference arrived in Virginia, so I decided to check whether VSP might stand for [Virginia State Papers](https://www.familysearch.org/search/catalog/76799?availability=Family%20History%20Library).

---

[Volume 1 of the Calendar of Virginia state papers and other manuscripts](https://archive.org/details/calendarvirgini12palmgoog/page/n274/mode/2up) is also available on archive.org.  James Wood appears on page 185 in the:

> List of Rebel Prisoners Imported by Capt: Edw'd TrafFord, in the Elizabeth & Anne, from Liverpole -

[image: List of rebel prisoners from Virginia State Papers volume 1]

As you can see, James Wood was listed as one of the 83 prisoners not indented (the list continues onto the next page).

So, **VSP.1.185** would appear to be ***Calendar of Virginia state papers. Volume 1. Page 185***.